# getLastKnowLocation return null

Tags: java, android

I was making an application, which has a MapView, in which I want to show a marker in the position obtained from the gps of the device when I press a button. The problem I have is that the first time I enter the mapview activity, the getLastKnowLocation returns null so it doesn't put the marker on the map, however if I go back to the MainActivity and then to the activity of the mapview ,I get a position and the marker is put on the map.

I do not know if I should use another method instead of getLastKnowLocation.

I put the code in which I have not yet implemented the GPS permission and the active GPS verification.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incidencia_mapa);

    bt_getgps=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_getgps);
    bt_getgps.setOnClickListener(this);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_incidencia);


    if (mapView != null) {
        mapView.onCreate(null);
        mapView.onResume();
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //SOLICITUD DE PERMISOS
        return;
    }


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

   if (location == null) {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }


    if(location != null){
        lat=location.getLatitude();
        longi= location.getLongitude();

    }


}
```

Onclick:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {

    if (lat != 0 && longi != 0) {

        place = new LatLng(lat, longi);


        marcador = new MarkerOptions();
        marcador.position(place);
        marcador.title("Zona del incidencia");
        marcador.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_incidencia_mapa));
        marcador.draggable(true);


        gMap.setMinZoomPreference(5);
        gMap.addMarker(marcador);

        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 17));

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());


        try {
            direciones = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, longi, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        calle = direciones.get(0).getAddressLine(0);


        Toast.makeText(this, direciones.get(0).getAddressLine(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        bt_getgps.setText(direciones.get(0).getAddressLine(0));



    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay longitud ni latitud", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: getLastKnowLocation returns null if no location was stored on the API before accessing (such reiniting the cellphone), you must waiit for locationManager.requestLocationUpdates to respond on the listener you added, there you will have a valid location

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem using the override method onLocationChanged to set the marker each time the location change.

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 1):

getLastKnowLocation returns null if no location was stored on the API before accessing (such reiniting the cellphone), you must waiit for locationManager.requestLocationUpdates to respond on the listener you added, there you will have a valid location.

getLastKnowLoation IF NOT NULL is a good starting point for a mapapplicaiton, but you should update trough requestLocationUpdates